# C++: checking if an object is non-empty in order to index each output with cout

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I am working on 1.20 out of C++ primer. I am trying to allow the user to input as many items as they see fit and the output would then be `Item no. is item`. For each entry, no. will increment by one as long as `item` is not empty.

> I am trying to get my program to check that user inputs a sales item in order to index each item.

My code is below:

```
/* http://www.informit.com/title/0321714113 contains a copy of Sales_item.h
 * in the chapter 1 code directory. Copy that file to your pwd. Use it to
 * wrtie a program that reads a set of book sales transactions, writing each
 * transaction to the standard output.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "IncC++files/1/Sales_item.h"

int main() {
  Sales_item item;  // call the item argument in Sales_item.h
  // prompt the user for the desired information to enter
  // std::string is used for long strings that run to multiple lines
  std::string my_phrase = "Input ISBN, number of copies sold, and"
                          " price sold and when complete enter C-d";
  std::cout << my_phrase << std::endl;
  /* defined while to allow users to continually enter in items until stopped
   * by C-d
   */
  for (int i = 0; i >= 0; ++i) {  // index the item number for the count
    while (std::cin >> item) {
      if (item != NULL) {
        // if item is not empty add one for the next item number
        i += 1;
        std::cout << "Item " << i << " is " << item << std::endl;
      } 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is trying to determine if item is empty.

```
exercise1_20.cpp:24:16: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are
‘Sales_item’ and ‘long int’)
       if (item != NULL) {
```

> What operator will allow me to check if `item` is non-empty?

---

The books C++ code for `Sales_item.h` for a linux system:

```
/*
 * This file contains code from "C++ Primer, Fourth Edition", by Stanley B.
 * Lippman, Jose Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo, and is covered under the
 * copyright and warranty notices given in that book:
 * 
 * "Copyright (c) 2005 by Objectwrite, Inc., Jose Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo."
 * 
 * 
 * "The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book,
 * but make no expressed or implied warranty of any kind and assume no
 * responsibility for errors or omissions. No liability is assumed for
 * incidental or consequential damages in connection with or arising out of the
 * use of the information or programs contained herein."
 * 
 * Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in
 * association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or
 * reproduced.Any commercial use of this code requires the explicit written
 * permission of the publisher, Addison-Wesley Professional, a division of
 * Pearson Education, Inc. Send your request for permission, stating clearly
 * what code you would like to use, and in what specific way, to the following
 * address: 
 * 
 *  Pearson Education, Inc.
 *  Rights and Contracts Department
 *  75 Arlington Street, Suite 300
 *  Boston, MA 02216
 *  Fax: (617) 848-7047
*/ 

#ifndef SALESITEM_H
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here


#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
friend bool operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
// other members as before
public:
    // added constructors to initialize from a string or an istream
    Sales_item(const std::string &book):
              isbn(book), units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);
    // other members as before

public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    double avg_price() const;
    bool same_isbn(const Sales_item &rhs) const
        { return isbn == rhs.isbn; }
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item(): units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
// private members as before
private:
    std::string isbn;
    unsigned units_sold;
    double revenue;

};


// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool 
operator==(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
           lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
       lhs.same_isbn(rhs);
}

inline bool 
operator!=(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

using std::istream; using std::ostream;

// assumes that both objects refer to the same isbn
inline
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; 
    revenue += rhs.revenue; 
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same isbn
inline
Sales_item 
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy lhs into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of rhs 
    return ret;           // return ret by value
}

inline
istream& 
operator>>(istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.isbn >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else 
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

inline
ostream& 
operator<<(ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn << "\t" << s.units_sold << "\t" 
        << s.revenue << "\t" <<  s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

inline
double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold) 
        return revenue/units_sold; 
    else 
        return 0;
}


#endif
```

Comment: Question: Is this post a copyright violation?

Comment: @DieterLücking that code can be found freely online [here](http://www.informit.com/title/0321714113) provided by the authors. Also, it says, "Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or reproduced." I mentioned the book, provided the link in my comment, and the authors name are in the text blurp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is used for pointers and pointers only.  Now that we have C++11 you should use its better counterpart `nullptr`

That aside your input operator sets the object to a blanck object using the default constructor so you should just check to see if your `item` is the same as a default `Sales_item`.

```
if (item != NULL)
```

becomes

```
if (item != Sales_item())
```

EDIT

<s>You also need to define a default constructor since you have provided a user defined constructor.</s>

EDIT2

You should group your constructors together instead of having them on opposite side of the class.

Comment: The unorganized code has a default constructor (I missed that, too)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by define a default constructor; however, changing `NULL` to `Sales_item()` was what was required.